# Android GPS Conversion from Objective-C

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c

What is the equivalent Objective-C snippet for IPhone in Java for Android.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
  [locationManager setDelegate:self];

  [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
  [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  NSLog(@"%@",newLocation);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location %@",error);
}
```

Comment: At stackoverflow we are happy to provide the key-solutions not the converted code snippet which can be copied directly. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `LocationManager` class that you will need to use.  This article has a great description of how to use it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html